# Twitter search API refresh_url is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I am making a GET request to twitter to receive a JSONP object back of most recent posts of a specific tag. Once I receive the data I loop through the results array getting each tweet individually.

My problem I am having is that **console.log(data.results[i].refresh_url);** is giving me an undefined value. So my question is:

1. Do you receive a **refresh_url** variable on all searches?
2. If not, how is refresh_url used? I would have to find the latest post id in the loop and re-query using **since_id=** which defeats the purpose of using refresh_url.

> ```
> $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?&callback=?&q=css", function(data) {
>     for(var i in data.results)
>     {
>          console.log(data.results[i].refresh_url);
>     }           
> });
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for refresh_url in the wrong place. It's outside of the result set.

Replace your logging line with

```
console.log(data.refresh_url);
```

This will give you to the URL to refresh from.